# Kernel panic after upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: upgrade

Today I've upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 using Ubuntu "Software Update". The download and installation went fine, till I did a restart. At some point the boot stops and the shift-lock LED is blinking on the keyboard. I've selected the recovery entry in the grub and then the following error message can be seen:

```
kernel panic not syncing unable to mount root fs on unkonown-block(0,0)
```

What can I do to fix this error?

If I boot older grub entries like kernel 3.19.0-31 it works.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to boot the old kernel 3.19.0-31 and do

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Exact same problem, and this solved it for me. I had a slightly different version for my previous kernel, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but this didn't work for me... I had to select the **wily-proposed** in software updates and then in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Rebooted and everything seems to be working fine now with Ubuntu 15.10 and the 4.2.0-21-generic kernel. Hope this helps someone!